# Extracting geometry from feature collection in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry, extract, feature-extraction, feature-collection

I have a feature collection containing thousands of feature. They are categorized into 10 classes. As you can see in the picture, these features are spread irregularly. I need to merge their geometries and extract the outline for clipping with image composite purpose. [image]

How do I do this? I have tried to extract the geometry of this feature collection and I got a geometry collection of 14k geometries.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the bounding geometry of the feature collection like so:

```
var bounds = polygons.geometry().bounds();
```

Where `polygons` is your feature collection.

[image]

Or the convex hull if you want to constrain the geometry tightly to your feature collection:

```
var bounds = polygons.geometry().convexHull();
```

[image]